# Submit form, visit next page, set session variables

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

I am working on a configuration proces with 6 steps. In each step I use a form which I submit and save the input data in SESSION variables.

On each step I have a "next button" which needs to submit the form of the page and redirects to the next step.

This piece of code checks if the submit button "wz_submit1" isset, then save the variables.

```
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit1'])) :

    // Save wz_width in session
    $wz_width = $_POST['wz_width'];
    $_SESSION['wz_width'] = $wz_width;

    // Save wz_height in session
    $wz_height = $_POST['wz_height'];
    $_SESSION['wz_height'] = $wz_height;

endif;
```

This is the "next" button:

```
<a class="wz_next_button" href="http://www.mynextstepurl.test">Next step</a>
```

This is my form:

```
    <form id="wz_form1" method="post">


        <ul class="wz_input">

            <li>
                <label>A</label>
                <input name="wz_width" id="wz_width" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_width'])) : echo $_SESSION['wz_width']; endif; ?>" />
                <span>mm</span>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label>B</label>
                <input name="wz_height" id="wz_height" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_height'])) : echo $_SESSION['wz_height']; endif; ?>" />
                <span>mm</span>
            </li>

        </ul><!--End wz_input-->

        <input name="wz_submit1" type="hidden" />

    </form>
```

If I use a normal submit button for "wz_submit1" it submits the form right and saves the variables in session. But after that there's no redirect to next page.

If I put a onclick form submit on the "next" link, the redirect to next page goes right but my variables doesn't get set.

I hope you understand my problem and hope you can help me.

If you have a better idea on how doing it (for example without a form for each page) then let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you started the session at the top of your every page? i.e. `session_start();`

Comment: Yes I have started the session.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way... when form submits and all the variable gets saved then it will redirect to your next page...

```
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit1'])) :

// Save wz_width in session
$wz_width = $_POST['wz_width'];
$_SESSION['wz_width'] = $wz_width;

// Save wz_height in session
$wz_height = $_POST['wz_height'];
$_SESSION['wz_height'] = $wz_height;
 header('Location : www.yournextpage.com');
endif;
```

your next button and from will be...

```
 <form method="post" action="samefile.php">
     //your other fields
    <input type="submit" value="next" name="wz_submit1"/>
 </form>
```